# I can't login with WebSecurity.Login and I get WebSecurity.CurrentUserId as -1.

Tags: model-view-controller, authentication

I am trying to register a user and place his order in same action for unregistered users. Please see problematic part of my code below.  I get WebSecurity.CurrentUserId as -1 here. Therefore I cant find users and add user info to order. What is wrong here. It should be Id of newly registered user. Thanks for your helps.

```
WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(UpperEmail, user.Password, new { user.Password, user.PasswordConfirm, user.Email, user.Name }, false);

                        int userId = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Email == user.Email).Id;
                        if (!Roles.RoleExists("User"))
                            Roles.CreateRole("User");
                        Roles.AddUserToRole(UpperEmail, "User");
                        WebSecurity.Login(UpperEmail, user.Password);

                        neworder.user = db.Users.Find(WebSecurity.CurrentUserId);
                        neworder.UserId = WebSecurity.CurrentUserId;
                        neworder.PaymentStatus = PaymentStatus.Onaylandi;I
```